# Posting image using tumblr

Tags: android, http-post, tumblr

```
 {"meta":{"status":401,"msg":"Not Authorized"},"response":[]}
```

Tumblr gives above result while posting image.

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse resp = null;
String result = null;
HttpPost hpost = new HttpPost("http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/" + username              
                                                         +".tumblr.com/post");
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", "photo"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("caption", "hello"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("source", "url_of_the_image"));


        String debug = "";
        try {
            hpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(
                    nameValuePairs));
            consumer.sign(hpost);
            resp = client.execute(hpost);
            result = EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity());
            Log.v("result >>", result);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            debug += e.toString();
        } catch (OAuthMessageSignerException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OAuthExpectationFailedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OAuthCommunicationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I need to post the image in tumblr. Give me some solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a third-party library? The Temboo SDK (free account required) includes methods to create Tumblr photo posts either by passing a photo URL or the Base64 encoded content of the photo. Take a look at:

https://www.temboo.com/library/Library/Tumblr/Post/CreatePhotoPostWithURL/ https://www.temboo.com/library/Library/Tumblr/Post/CreatePhotoPostWithImageFile/

Full disclosure -- I work at Temboo.